# UIWebView can't load pdf files after adding missing constraints

Tags: pdf, uiwebview, constraints

My app works fine before adding constraints to UIWebView. However, there is an error:

```
DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.
```

The app still works and shows the pdf file. After adding some constraints, it won't show the pdf file (it shows blank), and the error code is still there.

Here are some pictures:

**PIC 1:**

[image]

**PIC 2:**

[image]

This is my code:

```
        {
            NSString* tutorialView = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %i",tutorialNumber];
            NSURL *pathToView = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]    pathForResource:tutorialView ofType:@"pdf"]];
            [_webView2 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pathToView]];

        }
```

Is there a better way to view PDF files? I'm new to iOS programming. Sorry for stupid question

Comment: I think there is some problem with PDF file itself, what you are doing is correct, you can view PDF on UIWebView, try with other PDF see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following. Its works perfectly fine with me :)

```
UIWebView *pdf = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGM(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name Of PDF FIle" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
pdf.scalesPageToFit = YES;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];<br>
[pdf loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:pdf];
```